# How to retrieve valid access token from keychain with GTM OAuth2.0

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, access-token, keychain

I'm trying to obtain a valid access token for an OAuth authentication. I'm trying to understand the process of authentication with oAuth 2.0. I want to understand how to use

```
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:clientID:clientSecret:]
```

My final goal is to allow the app to remember an user and avoid sign in form each time the user launch the app.

When I'm calling

```
-(void) getAuthFromKeychain{
self.myAuth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:keychainItemName
                                                                    clientID:clientID
                                                                clientSecret:clientSecret];
}
```

I'm getting an myAuth object but it has only 6 parameters:

- UserID
- scope
- serviceProvider
- isVerified
- email
- refresh_token

No access_token, expire_in or token_type.

What is the next step once I've my incomplete auth?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually put in an authorisation request by going to the authorise URL first and receiving the token back from that call, when the user grants access, before you store the auth object and thus the token to the keychain.

You're trying to retrieve an auth object from the keychain which hasn't got any token information.

[This Guide](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/GTMOAuthIntroduction#Signing_in_to_Services) should help.